# Is static typing a subset of dynamic typing?

Tags: dynamic, types, static

I was going to add this as a comment to my previous question about type theory, but I felt it probably deserved its own exposition:

If you have a dynamic typing system and you add a "type" member to each object and verify that this "type" is a specific value before executing a function on the object, how is this different than static typing? (Other than the fact that it is run-time instead of compile-time).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

static typing happens at compile-time, not at run-time! And that difference is essential!!

See B.Pierce's book [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) for more.

Comment: Well, yes, I mentioned that.  Is that the only difference though, or is there a deeper theoretical difference?

Comment: But that difference is deep and theoretical.

Comment: Ah, I believe that's what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: ... you wouldn't happen to have a summary of it would you?  (Don't worry -- I'll get around to reading it).

Answer (score 9):

Technically, it actually is the other way round: a "dynamically typed" language is a special case of a statically typed language, namely one with only a single type (in the mathematical sense).  That at least is the view point of many in the type systems community.

Edit regarding static vs dynamic checking: only local properties can be checked dynamically, whereas properties that require some kind of global knowledge *cannot*. Think of properties such as something being unique, something not being aliased, a computation being free of race conditions. A suitable static type system *can* verify such properties, because it has the ability to establish certain invariants on the context of the expression that is being checked.